# Updating dictionaries of list from another dictionary python

Tags: python

I have two list of dictionaries: I am trying to compare test2 with test1 and update accordingly.

```
test1 = [{'names': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'country': 'USA',
  'state': 'Texas'},

 {'names': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  'country': 'Australia',
  'state': 'Melbourne'},

 {'names': ['i', 'j', 'k'],
  'country': 'canada',
  'state': 'Toronto'},

 {'names': ['l', 'm', 'n'],
  'country': 'Austria',
  'state': 'Burgenland'}]

test2 = [{'code': 4286,
'list_of_countries': ['USA',
            'Australia',
            'Colombia',
            'Denmark',
            'Greece',
            'Iceland']},
 {'code':4287,
 'list_of_countries': ['Texas',
            'Argentina',
            'Austria',
            'Bangladesh', 'canada']}]
```

Expected Output:

```
test2 = [{'names':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
        'country': ['USA', 'Australia'],
        'state': ['Texas', 'Melbourne'],
        'code':4286},

        {'names':['i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'],
        'country': ['canada', 'Austria'],
        'state': ['Toronto','Burgenland'],
        'code':4287}]
```

Tried below snippet: By searching the test1 country in test2 list_of_countries:

```
for i in test1:
    for j in test2:
        a = []
        if i.get('country') in j.get('list_of_countries'):
           a.append({'country':i.get('country'), 'state':i.get('state'})
           j.update(a)
```

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: How big is the data going to get? Do you have to keep the format for your dictionary in test1? Without changing the format of your test1 dictionary to have the keys be the country and state, the best you will be able to do is the nested for loops the way you have them which will end up running in On^2 time, if the list is small, who cares. If it is big, that'll be a problem

Comment: @DaniMesejo I am collecting data from different parsed dictionaries and trying to plot some graph in flask based webapp.

Comment: @MichaelRobellard The data will be not too big, but minimal as per the design i know.

Comment: @MichaelRobellard. How many countries are there? How many states? Certainly not enough to worry about polynomial complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform `test2` to a dictionary, associating each entry in `list_of_countries` with their proper key. Then, you can use this result for grouping:

```
test2 = [{'code': 4286, 'list_of_countries': ['USA', 'Australia', 'Colombia', 'Denmark', 'Greece', 'Iceland']}, {'code': 4287, 'list_of_countries': ['Texas', 'Argentina', 'Austria', 'Bangladesh', 'canada']}]
test1 = [{'names': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'country': 'USA', 'state': 'Texas'}, {'names': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'country': 'Australia', 'state': 'Melbourne'}, {'names': ['i', 'j', 'k'], 'country': 'canada', 'state': 'Toronto'}, {'names': ['l', 'm', 'n'], 'country': 'Austria', 'state': 'Burgenland'}]
d = {i:k['code'] for k in test2 for i in k['list_of_countries']}
```

---

Now, you can create a series of [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)s associated with the country code. By looping over the country/state dicts in `test1`, you can keep a running update of the states and countries that are associated with each code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_d = dict(zip(d.values(), [defaultdict(list) for _ in d]))
for i in test1:
   for a, b in i.items():
     new_d[d[i['country']]][a].append(b)

r = [{'code':a, **b, 'names':[j for k in b['names'] for j in k]} for a, b in new_d.items()]
```

The final list comprehension transforms `new_d` to your desired format, a list of dictionaries.

Output:

```
[{'code': 4286, 'names': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'country': ['USA', 'Australia'], 'state': ['Texas', 'Melbourne']}, {'code': 4287, 'names': ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'], 'country': ['canada', 'Austria'], 'state': ['Toronto', 'Burgenland']}]
```

Comment: This worked fine. Thanks a ton. Now, I am having hard time to understand the logic...

Comment: @louis See my recent edit, as I augmented my original explanation. Please let me know if it is clearer now.

Comment: @Ajaz1234: Thanks, I understood!